# How do I lower the water even more?

Tags: fez

I've already gotten all 64 cube/anti-cube bits in *Fez* and finished the game, but there are two doors which remain inaccessible to me. The 64-bit door under the little tree island, and the door underneath the main warp gate.

I've already reduced the flow at the waterfall, of course, but I can't find anything else which will allow me to lower the water a little bit more so I can reach these two rooms.

The 64-bit door even opens when I approach, but the water is just high enough that I'm swimming, and entering the door is impossible (i.e. the <kbd>Up</kbd> key does nothing).
[image: island door]

What do I do? I've looked through a dozen walkthroughs, to no avail!

Comment: Are you sure you've used lever for water level to the end? IIRC, each "world turn" lowers water for certain amount, and it is possible to rotate lever not to the very end, and leave water a little higher than min possible level.

Comment: @lentinant That was it! Thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious. Care to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to partially lower the water if you are not rotating corresponding lever to the very end. Check if you have used it to the end.